# Insert javascript in XSL

Tags: javascript, xslt

I am trying to insert a javascript variable in my XLS page (called by XML) to show/write the name of the page. I would like to use the name of the page as a variable.

This is what I am using :

between the

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 
<![CDATA[
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var page = sPage.replace(".xml", ""); 
]]>
</SCRIPT>
```

and

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 
<![CDATA[
document.write(page);
]]>
</SCRIPT>
```

The javascript works with IE (I can write the name of the page xml) but not in firefox (33)... Have you any idea if is it possible to load this javascript ?

Comment: You use XSL, XLS and xslt here - What do you mean? Xslt? What does this question have to do with xslt, I don't see any connection. Also, XML can not call anything, it is markup language. Please clarify what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is not supported in HTML result documents of client-side XSLT transformations, see the Mozilla XSLT FAQ: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#What_about_document.write.3F.

But you could place a `<span id="pageName"></span>` in the result document followed by e.g.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('pageName').innerHTML = page;
</script>
```

or it might be safer to write an onload handler in the `head` section

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('pageName').innerHTML = page;
};
</script>
```

that sets the innerHTML of the span as needed.